# Can anyone explain this code for me? Thanks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey what are event and progress in function body from `function(event, progress, stepValue)`?

```
$(".circle .bar")
    .circleProgress(options)
    .on(
        "circle-animation-progress",
        function (event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .find("span")
            .text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
         }
     );
```

Comment: Is this code a part of testing, e.g. cypress?

Comment: It's a callback which been fired on any progress change. This function invoked by the library with the parameters `event, progress, stepValue`. What exactly these parameters? Usually the docs say. What library are you using?

Comment: High level explanation (based on the question *title* which doesn't exactly match the *question*):  Your code initiates the jquery-circle-progress plugin on an element with class "bar" inside an element with class "circle".  Every time the circle animates you get an event which updates every span inside the .bar's parent element and outputs the current step value and then **incorrectly** adds a "%" sign (this may be correct if the value is 1.0).  This should probably use `progress` rather than `stepValue`